# How is allocation ratio in container?

Tags: docker, containers

How is allocation ratio in container?

In Openstack there are configutation in `nova.conf`:

```
#cpu_allocation_ratio=16.0
 
#ram_allocation_ratio=1.5
```

so we know the good ratio should be CPU 1:16 and RAM 1:1.5, but how about in docker if we set multiple containers in a 8 processor CPU when we want to maximize CPU and memory usage?

---

**EDIT-01**

I know how to limit container CPU usage, but this is not my requirement.

I mean, if in the OpenStack, there have 8 logical cores host, I can run as much as 128(8*16.0) 1 core VMs.

how about in docker?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to limit docker daemon general resource usage, please advise this question: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/537645/how-to-limit-docker-total-resources

If you want on a per container basis, docker also has the option to allocate CPU and memory resources per container, see [here](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/resource_constraints/) or for example (allocating half of the CPUs to the container):

```
docker run -it --cpus=".5" ubuntu /bin/bash
```

if you dont limit them they all see theire memory and CPU available as the configured system total (if my machine has 16vCPU 16GB RAM each container would think it has 16vCPU and 16GB RAM available only for it) which could crash your vm and subsequently your containers if the containers would try to consume more memory than available on the machine.